# How to share a disposable resource between Android components

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app that is composed of an `Activity`, some `BroadcastReceiver`s and a `Service`. Each of these components needs to interact with a resource that requires special setup and teardown.  Thus:

1. If one component (e.g. `Activity`) stands up the resource, and another component (e.g. `BroadcastReceiver`) is activated, I'd prefer the latter component to use the same instance of that resource (to avoid its setup overhead).
2. When the first component is destroyed (e.g. user closes UI), but another component is still using the resource (e.g. `Service`), I'd prefer for that shared resource to remain alive.
3. When all components are disposed of (no UI, no `Service`, nothing for `BroadcastReceiver` to receive), I need that shared resource to be gracefully torn down.

The resource in question manages an authenticated connection to some IoT brokers.  When no longer needed, the broker needs to be unsubscribed form, logged out of, etc.  But at the same time, I don't want to have each component managing its own private instance because the broker service throttles and restricts multiple, simulatenous logins.  Hence, a shared instance.

While I can lazily instantiate and set up the instance on first request for it, I'm not sure how best to tear it down when no longer needed.

My understanding is that `App.onTerminate()` is not to be relied upon:

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so.

The only other technique I can think of is to use a shared singleton and reference counting.

Is there a more "Androidy" way I should use instead?

Comment: "My understanding is that App.onTerminate() is not to be relied upon" -- if that's an option, then you could just not tear it down, and it will go away when your process does. To me, that doesn't quite feel like it matches your requirements, and for those, I think reference-counting in one form or fashion is your best bet.